# Unable to connect to AWS RDS MariaDB using Sequelize in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I am working on a Node.js project that connects to a MariaDB database using Sequelize. The connection works fine in my local environment, but when I try to connect to a MariaDB database hosted on AWS RDS, it fails.

I have verified that the AWS RDS connection works using MySQL Workbench, but my Node.js project throws the following error:

**Unable to connect to the database: SequelizeConnectionError: (conn=1690, no: 45012, SQLState: 08S01) Connection timeout: failed to create socket after 1001ms**

I tried look like this:

```
const dbConfig = require('../config/dbConfig');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
    host: dbConfig.HOST,
    port: dbConfig.PORT,
    dialect: "mariadb",
    operatorsAliases: 0,
    define: {
        freezeTableName: true  // it's default behavior is to modified table name automatic, so we restrict it with this param
    },
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }
});

sequelize.authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('DB Connected...');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Unable to connect to the database: ${error}`);
    })
```

Comment: While I am using MySQL instead of MariaDB (that means I created MySQL DB in RDS and installed mysql2 dependency in node js), it's working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your RDS instance publicly accessible?

1. You can check that one by going to **Connectivity & security** and if the **Publicly accessible** is set to **No**, you cannot access your instance from public workspace (just from within the VPC).
   [image: Public access]

To enable public access, you can go to **Modify** and under **Connectivity** go to Additional configuration and set Public Access to "Publicly Accessible".
Also, when asked, do the changes immediately and not on the next schedule - you need to wait for a minute or two until the modification is done before being able to access the instance.

2. Check if the underlying EC2 instance is reachable - go security group of the RDS instance, under the **Connectivity** tab.
   [image: Connectivity tab]
3. In the inbound rules of the security group, add MySQL/Aurora port and My IP as the Source.
   [image: Add My IP as the Source for the EC2 security group]
4. Make sure that either you have a database created (because you don't have by default). If you haven't provide `null` as the dbConfig.DB value:

```
const dbConfig = require('./config/dbConfig');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(null, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
host: dbConfig.HOST,
port: dbConfig.PORT,
dialect: 'mariadb',
dialectOptions: {
  // Your additional options here
},
pool: {
  max: 5,
  min: 0,
  acquire: 30000,
  idle: 10000
  }
});

sequelize.authenticate()
.then(() => {
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});
```

You should be able to see the following message:

```
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Connection has been established successfully.
```

Comment: 1. yes my RDS instance is publicly accessible.

2. And in the inbound rules of the security group, I have added **All traffic** port and **Anywhere-IPv4** as the Source

Comment: Did you try adding a new rule with your IP address as the source, and MySQL/Aurora port? It doesn't work for me either if I remove that.